# How to use gorm with Beego

Tags: go, orm, beego, go-gorm

Beego ORM is somehow incomplete for now (for example it doesn't support foreign key constraints). So I've decided to use [gorm](https://github.com/beego/orm-benchmark) with Beego. What is proper way of doing that? I've seen the sample code from gorm:

```
import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
)

func main() {
  db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=myhost user=gorm dbname=gorm sslmode=disable password=mypassword")
  defer db.Close()
}
```

But do I have to connect to database each time in every controller function? Is there a way to use something like long polling connections?

Answer (score 3):

gorm uses sql.DB type embedded in gorm.DB under the hood which

> DB is a database handle representing a pool of zero or more
>   underlying connections. It's safe for concurrent use by multiple
>   goroutines. The sql package creates and frees connections
>   automatically; it also maintains a free pool of idle connections.

So you can use obtained DB globally in your code,
if you want level of isolation in request handling use transaction

```
tr:=db.Begin()
```

Comment: Could you provide more elaborate example? How exactly "obtained DB" (which is defined in `main.go`, if I understand correctly) would become accessible in other files/packages?

Answer (score 1):

So, as @Uvelichitel pointed out, your option is to define your `db` connection at the global level and to use it from a desired place (probably main function to open a connection and model layer to query for results).

So you could basically have a file containing your db connection logics:

```
// appname/conn.go

package db

import (
  "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
  ...
)

var (
  // this one gonna contain an open connection
  // make sure to call Connect() before using it
  Conn *gorm.DB
)

func Connect(dbConnString string) (*gorm.DB, error) {
  db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", dbConnString)
  Conn = db
  return db, err
}
```

After you call `db.Connect` from your `main.go` you are free to use an opened connection `db.Conn` from anywhere of your application (just make sure you're importing this package to the places of use).

```
import "appname/db"

func main() {
  conn, _ := db.Connect("host=localhost user=postgres ...")
  // db.Conn is initialized and ready for usage anywhere else
```

The same result could be achieved within a single `main.go` file, moving global variable declaration and a connection logics straight there.

Comment: How do I stop beego from loading the models as it's own?